# Table View Cell Image resizes when swipe to edit

Tags: image, constraints, tableview, edit, swipe

I have Constraints set for the image view in the background but for some reason when I swipe to get the Delete the image gets resized. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First Try to changing your imageView content mode to .AspectFit. The second image is actually correct if you want the whole image to show. It looks like it's redrawing image when it starts becoming interactive.  Try calling cell.yourImageView.layoutIfNeeded()  when loading the cell to fix your problem.  If this is a UIViewController and that does not work try moving the code for autodiminsions  to the actual functions.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

}

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return closeGuess //maybe 200
```

}

Comment: Tried adding cell.yourImageView.layoutIfNeeded() inside  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     but that didn't work. I also tried adding the two functions heightforrow and estimate hightforrow but still same results

Comment: Try changing you imageview contentmode property to .AspectFit